# MongoDB aggregate lookup let variables problem

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've create a mongoplayground to make it easier to understand.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/8zhkcMyLkmy

Basically, I'm stuck between line 108 ~ 111, because in MongoDB Compass the same aggregate pipeline doesn't work.

Here's the images:

[image: Empty lookupResult]

If I just change '$$date' to its date:
[image: with string instead date]

Even if I insert the variable inside date function:
[image: variable inside date function]

Does anyone have any thoughts in why it doesn't work in compass and works in mongoplayground?

Comment: Have you checked if your MongoCompass is on the newest version? or at least equivalent to Mongo Playground (5.0.6)

Comment: Hi @MaximilianDolbaum yes, MongoDB Compass is on the newest version 1.30.1

Comment: What if you convert the date string to date? `$lte: [ { $toDate: "$date" }, { $toDate: "$$date" }]`

Comment: Yes... It worked @YongShun! It's really weird because in mongo playground we didn't need to do it! Thanks a lot for advance. Post the answer for others users know it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For best practice, when comparing date string, it is required to convert as `date` first (via [`$toDate`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/)).

```
$lte: [ { $toDate: "$date" }, { $toDate: "$$date" }]
```

[Comparison/Sort Order (MongoDB Manual) - String section](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/)

> By default, MongoDB uses the simple binary comparison to compare strings.

Hence, comparing dates in string format will lead to an inaccurate result.